# Layouts sometimes overlap in android fragment

Tags: android

My code works very well
But sometimes layouts overlap
The reason for this code is that the first fragment should not be reloaded.
And the second and third fragments should always be reloaded

Have you ever had problems with layout overlapping code?

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem)
{
    Fragment selectedFragment = null;


    switch (menuItem.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.timer:
            fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(fragment1).commit();
            active = fragment1;
            break;

        case R.id.favorite:
            fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).commit();
            fm.beginTransaction().detach(fragment2).attach(fragment2).commit();
            fm.beginTransaction().show(fragment2).commit();

            active = fragment2;


            break;

        case R.id.calendar:
            fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).commit();
            fm.beginTransaction().detach(fragment3).attach(fragment3).commit();
            fm.beginTransaction().show(fragment3).commit();

            active = fragment3;

            break;
    }

    return true;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding you have to show one screen based on menu click so why not you're using FrameLayout in xml and based on click or any event just add or replace the fragment. Make 3 different Fragment class and use interface or any latest arch component provide by Google.